# How to get credentials from a String with many characters with substr and store them in variables

Tags: php, regex, php-7

Hello everyone i have a String that contains ServerName,databaseName,Username and password as below.

server_name::IMACW10\COZMOSQLEXPRESS @database_name::OneTwoThreePet username::pauline_pet databasePass::root

I need to find a way to substr and get the databaseName,ServerName,Username and pass and store them on variables so that i can be able to use the credentials to connect to a server

After sub-string i would like them to be in the below format
[image]

Comment: Regex will be the way for this problem, add the regex tag to get some of the regex pro's involved

Comment: @LiamG added thanks

Comment: Can you please post the text directly instead of screenshots.

Comment: Please remove the images and put the actual strings in here. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some help on how to write a good question that people would be more willing to answer

Comment: Please if anybody can help i need the code I am a developer

Comment: learn to use the list command and explode and foreach.

Comment: Here you go `server_name::(\S*)(?!\S).+?@database_name::(\S*)(?!\S).+?username::(\S*)(?!\S).+?databasePass::(\S*)(?!\S)`

Comment: Developers are supposed to *write* code, not beg for it on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non Regex version of what you are trying to achieve.

```
$str = "server_name::IMACW10\COZMOSQLEXPRESS @database_name::OneTwoThreePet username::pauline_pet databasePass::root";
$test = explode(" ", $str);
$array = array();
foreach($test as $key){
    $newkey = strtok($key,":");
    $array[$newkey] = substr($key, strpos($key, ":") + 2);   
}
list($server, $dbname, $username, $pass) = array_values($array);
echo '$serverName='.$server.'<br> $databaseName='.$dbname.'<br> $username='.$username.'<br> $pass='.$pass;
```

Output:

```
$serverName=IMACW10\COZMOSQLEXPRESS
$databaseName=OneTwoThreePet
$username=pauline_pet
$pass=root
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

For your example data you could first [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) one a whitespace and then for each items use explode again using `::` and take the second value from the array `[1]`.

Then you might use for example [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to create your variables.

```
$str = "server_name::IMACW10\COZMOSQLEXPRESS @database_name::OneTwoThreePet username::pauline_pet databasePass::root";
list($serverName, $databaseName, $username, $pass) = array_map(function ($x) {
    return explode('::', $x)[1];
}, explode(' ', $str));

echo sprintf("servername:%s<br>databasename:%s<br>username:%s<br>pass:%s",
    $serverName,
    $databaseName,
    $username,
    $pass
);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/EMWP4)

That would give you:

```
servername:IMACW10\COZMOSQLEXPRESS
databasename:OneTwoThreePet
username:pauline_pet
pass:root
```